# Undo recent "git add ." command fired on git bash

Tags: git

I have mistakenly did `git add .` Now I have multiple files in staging area. I know I can use `git reset` to unstage files but this would take most of my time.

I am looking for a solution that would save my time. Now I want to know that

- Is there a possible way to undo last `git add .` command fired on git. So that I don't have to do `git reset file` multiple times.
- If the above way is not possible then is there a way I could do reset multiple files using a single command.

Comment: simply do a `git reset`

Comment: No way to undo that. The best approach in the future are small commits. https://sethrobertson.github.io/GitBestPractices/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you have staged files you want to *keep* staged, or are you willing to have all files go back to *completely unstaged?*

The latter is very easy: use `git reset` with no additional arguments, as [galath commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42694707/undo-recent-command-fired-on-git-bash#comment72511840_42694707).  This does a `--mixed` reset:

- move the current branch to the named commit, but with no named commit, that means move the current branch to `HEAD`, and `HEAD` is the current commit, so we move the current commit to itself, which does nothing; then
- replace files in the index with their versions in the named commit (which, again, we didn't name, so that's the `HEAD` commit).

(These two steps are the `--soft` and `--mixed` parts; without `--hard`, `git reset` *skips* the third step of wiping out work-tree changes.  Obviously you don't want those wiped out, so you should not use `--hard`.)

The former is harder.  To get a list of all staged files, use:

```
git diff --cached --name-only
```

If you want to selectively re-set most, but not all, of these files, you can write those file names to a file (preferably outside your work-tree) such as `/tmp/list`, then edit the file to remove the names you want to keep staged.  Then:

```
git reset -- $(cat /tmp/list)
```

or:

```
xargs git reset -- < /tmp/list
```

to run `git reset --` on each path name.  This assumes there is no white-space in the file names; if there is, use additional shell trickery to break only at newlines (assuming no newlines in the path names).

If you had carefully staged *some* but not *all* of some files using `git add -p`, it *is* usually possible to recover these using `git fsck --lost-found` and poking through all the resulting "dangling blobs", but that's rarely worth the effort.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It appears this should work:
`git reset -p <file_name>`